# How to properly define classes to serialize them to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I'm building an app using Nondeterministic Finite Automaton which have to save it and read it from a file. I tried dozens of different methods with [XmlTags] and it still give me errors. Can You tell me how classes should be defined to be serialized by XML serializer?

```
 public class state
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string name
        { get; set; }

        public List<transition> transitions
        { get; set; }

        public state()
        {
        }
        public state(string Name)
        {
            name = Name;
        }

        public void addTransition(string Letter, state NextState)
        {
            bool found = false;
            foreach (transition tr in this.transitions)
            {
                if (tr.letter.Equals(Letter))
                {
                    tr.nextStates.Add(NextState);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (found == false)
                {
                    transitions.Add(new transition(Letter, NextState));
                }
            }
            if (found == false)
            {
                transitions.Add(new transition(Letter, NextState));
            }
        }
    }
    public class transition
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string letter
        { get; set; }
        public List<state> nextStates
        { get; set; }

        public transition()
        {
        }
        public transition(string Letter, state NextState)
        {
            letter = Letter;
            nextStates = new List<state>();
            nextStates.Add(NextState);
        }
    }

    public class automaton
    {
        public List<state> states
        { get; set; }

        public automaton()
        {
        }
        public bool isState(string StateName)
        {
            foreach (state st in states)
                if (st.name.Equals(StateName)) return true;
            return false;

        }
        public state getState(string StateName)
        {
            foreach (state st in states)            
                if (st.name.Equals(StateName)) return st;
            return new state(StateName);
        }
    }  


public class XMLReader
    {
        public static void NFAToXML(automaton Automaton, string Filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(automaton));
            TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@Filename);
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, Automaton);
            textWriter.Close();
        }
        public static automaton XMLToNFA(string Filename)
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<state>));
            TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(Filename);
            automaton automaton = new automaton();
            automaton.states= (List<state>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
            textReader.Close();
            return automaton;
        }

    }
```

I want my XML to look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<automaton xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <state name="q0" type="initial" >
        <transition letter="0">
          <state name="q1"></state>
          <state name="q3"></state>
        </transition>
        <transition letter="1">
          <state name="q0"></state>
          <state name="q2"></state>
        </transition>
    </state>
    <state name="q1">
        <transition letter="0">
        </transition>
        <transition letter="1">
          <state name="q3"></state>
        </transition>
    </state>
    <state name="q2" type="accepting">
        <transition letter="0">
          <state name="q1"></state>
        </transition>
        <transition letter="1">
          <state name="q0"></state>
          <state name="q2"></state>
        </transition>
    </state>
    <state name="q3">
        <transition letter="0">
          <state name="q1"></state>
        </transition>
        <transition letter="1">
          <state name="q1"></state>
          <state name="q2"></state>
        </transition>
    </state>
</automaton>
```

Please, help, I was trying to change it in many ways, but with no succes...

Comment: Well... What are the errors? If it throws an exception, be sure to dig through the inner-exceptions - it actually gives detailed info.

Answer (score 2):

State has a list of transitions, and each transition has a list of states.

This causes a circular reference when serializing. It should tell you this if you inspect the InnerException object of the exception you catch.

You'll need to either work around this, such as only writing the IDs of the instances, or use a serializer that supports references.

Comment: Just to say - this doesn't automatically mean it is recursive - but it looks like it may be in this case. Personally I'd create a new type that represents the state as it appears in a transition - minimal etc.

Answer (score 1):

The main error I can see (without a compiler) is the lists: to do a list without a wrapper element, use XmlElementAttribute:

```
 [XmlElement("transition")]
 public List<transition> transitions { get; set; }
```

You will need this on "states" too - `[XmlElement("state")]`

Comment: I added tag [Serializable] and [XmlElement("transition")] and state, but it still get error - "There was an error generating the XML document." Inner exception is "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type mojXML.state."

Comment: @saajuu yeah, the XmlElement is merely to adjust the shape so you don't get "states" in the XML (which you don't seem to want). If your model is recursive, XmlSerializer can't work with that. So: don't make a recursive model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `[Serializable]` attribute over your class to serialize/deserialize class objects. Refer to the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx) for more details.

```
[Serializable()]        
public class State
{ }
```

Comment: No you don't. XmlSerializer has never needed this. I don't know why this myth persists.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the XML you want, there is an easy trick:

- save the file as foo.xml
- at a vs command prompt, execute `xsd foo.xml` to generate foo.xsd
- now in the same propert execute `xsd foo.xsd /classes` to generate foo.cs

the foo.cs file now has a c# model that matches your XML.